# Loop over files names with any digit number in python

Tags: python-3.x

Let say I have 3 files in my /path1/folder :

```
fb.1.1_cluster_0003_model
fb.2.2_cluster_0001_model
fb.1.5_cluster_0002_model
```

And I would like to open each of them depending on a liste:

```
liste = ["cluster_0001","cluster_0003","cluster_0002"]
```

so something like :

```
for i in liste: 
    file = open("/path1/fb.[0-1].[0-1]_"+i+"_model")
```

but I do not know how to deal with the fact that the number.number could change at any time and be different within each i.

Does someone have an idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re
import os

#os.listdir(Your_path)
dir_list = ["fb.1.1_cluster_0003_model", "fb.2.2_cluster_0001_model", "fb.1.5_cluster_0002_model"]
liste = ["cluster_0001","cluster_0003","cluster_0002", "cluster_0000"]

pattern = "(" + "|".join(liste) + ")"
for filename in dir_list:
    if re.search(pattern, filename):
        with open(os.path.join("path1", filename)) as infile:
            data = infile.read()
```

Comment: Hello, I do not have access to a dir_list it is just an exemple, the number.number will change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You can put only the number to the list (may be useful if you want to use a range for example) and match them with regexp:

```
import re
import os

dir_list = ["fb.1.1_cluster_0003_model", "fb.2.2_cluster_0001_model", "fb.1.5_cluster_0002_model"]
liste = ["0001","0003","0002","0000"]

reg = re.compile("cluster_(?P<cluster_num>\d+)_model")
for filename in dir_list:
    match = reg.search(filename).groupdict()
    if 'cluster_num' in match.keys():
        if match['cluster_num'] in liste:
            with open(os.path.join("path1", filename)) as infile:
                data = infile.read()
```